# Using ZMQ in C # and Mac Os X

Tags: c#, macos, zeromq

I wanted to implement ICP on Mac OSX, so I learned about ZeroMQ through googling.
I installed ZeroMQ using the brew install zmq command
However, there is very little information about ZeroMq on Mac OSX, so I am having difficulty with some problems.

This is an example uploaded on the ZeroMQ homepage.

```
public static void HWClient(string[] args)
{

using (var context = new ZContext())
using (var requester = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.REQ))
{
    // Connect
    requester.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        string requestText = "Hello";
        Console.Write("Sending {0}...", requestText);

        // Send
        requester.Send(new ZFrame(requestText));

        // Receive
        using (ZFrame reply = requester.ReceiveFrame()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Received: {0} {1}!", requestText, reply.ReadString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I run these code, I'll get an exception `The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.lib.zmq' threw an exception.`
There are many ways to fix the exception, but there is no solution in Mac OSX.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the released version of https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4 works under MacOS X only under very special circumstances, due to several issues related to loading the native libzmq library. This is fixed to some degree in the master. There is now CI under MacOS X, so you can have a look at the CI script under https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/blob/master/build.sh for one way of installing and building that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd post this as a comment, but don't have the rep:

Have you tried using NetMQ (https://github.com/zeromq/netmq)?  I haven't used it on OSX (only Windows), but it's a native C# implementation of ZMQ that I've found to be pretty well designed, and in my opinion might be easier to get working than what you're using, which I assume is a C# wrapper around the C library.

Also, if you want help with the specific library that you're using, you should probably post what ways you've already tried to fix the exception, since you state there are "many ways to fix the exception, but there is no solution in Mac OSX".